# Random parking problem on a probability distribution

Tags: probability, reference-request

[Rényi's Parking Constants](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RenyisParkingConstants.html) comes up when one puts down unit length cars on a interval, such that the probability of covering any two interval is the same.

Are there any published results when the distribution is non-uniform?

Comment: If you don't get any good answers here in the next day or so, you might try this at Math Overflow.

Comment: This was asked recently @ MathOverflow and didn't get much response - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/50924/random-parking-problem-on-a-probability-distribution

Comment: @Dinesh @Mike Spivey: The question was asked on both sites the same day. @Chao Xu: You might care to specify whether the reference provided on the MO page mentioned by @Dinesh satisfied you or not and, if not, why it did not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one: Jean-François Marckert, *Parking with density*, Random Structures and Algorithms 18 (4), 364-380 (2001). A preprint version is available on [this page](http://www.labri.fr/perso/marckert/papers.html).