# The parking problem riddle

Tags: probability, random

Assume a street of 300 meters, that you can park your car alongside the pavement. Assume that there is a big parking problem in the area. Assume that the pavement is continuous, without interruptions, and that you can park alongside all of it. Assume that the length of a car is 3 meters long. Assume, for simplicity, that cars can park without space between them (bumper to bumper). Assume, that when a car comes to the street if chooses an equally random parking space (please try to express this randomness) from the free spaces left. Therefore, it may "ruin" parking places for other cars. Please try to determine what is the expectancy of cars the can park alongside the street.

Comment: This seems to answer the question: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RenyisParkingConstants.html. I've removed my answer, since it was wrong.

Comment: Hi, the link seems to be broken.. could you redirect me ?

Comment: It works, it's just slow I think. I found that link on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16078/random-parking-problem-on-a-probability-distribution, btw, which gets listed under "Related" right next to your question.. ;-)

Comment: @fgp: Hi, unfortunately i'm a law student lost in the world of math with this question (I do not understand anything from it), can you or someone else here explain it to me? 10X.

Comment: does this article part 3.2 solves the problem ? any1 ? [article](http://repositories.lib.utexas.edu/bitstream/handle/2152/18979/beckman_thesis.pdf?sequence=2)

Comment: does any1 have any other idea of how to solve this problem ? doesn't have to be the most complicated way.

Comment: Ok, I've summarized the results on that page and derived two estimates for the expectation you're looking for. Anything more would probably one to first see *how* those results are obtained, which would certainly be interesting but way to time consuming for me.

Comment: @user75013 I am curious, how does a law student end up being put in a position of writing a paper or doing a problem of this type? Perhaps your professor just wants you  describe what "expected value" means in this case.

Comment: So, to be clear, each new car that comes in will attempt to park at an *available* spot uniformly at random, noone will be so silly as to try to park where there is already a car, see there is a car in their way and give up even though there is a perfectly good spot a few feet away?  That's a shame because that would have made the problem much easier.

Comment: @JMoravitz I don't think that changes the problem at all: the distribution of the final configuration (where no more cars will fit) should be exactly the same.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ah, I suppose I had inserted a condition in my mind that wasn't there that there are $100$ total cars trying to park.  I was aiming to use a linearity of expectation argument, but at a glance my first impression is that it won't be so easy for the intended problem.

Comment: I vote against closing this question.  It seems clear enough to me, and if it someone does find it unclear, then, rather than closing it, a more constructive approach would be to ask in the comments for clarification; it is only twenty minutes old.

Comment: Please confirm that my addition of the phrases "uniformly distributed" is correct.

Comment: This classical "car parking problem" has first been treated by Rényi (1958), then by Dvoretzky and Robbins (1964). Google, and you will find several books treating it. The solution is not simple.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RenyisParkingConstants.html, if $M(n)$ is the expected number of cars of length 1 to fit onto a stripe of length $n$, you have $$
  m := \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{M(n)}{n} \approx 0.7476 \text{.}
$$

In other words, the *expected density* (i.e., the total length of the parked cars divided by the length of the pavement) goes to $0.7476\ldots$ as the pavement length goes to infinity. In your case that leads to an estimate for the expected number $N$ of 3m long cars on a 300m long pavement of $$
  \frac{3N}{300} \approx 0.7476 \implies N \approx 74.76 \text{.}
$$

A more precise estimate from that page is $$
  M(n) \approx mn + m - 1 \text{,}
$$
again for the expected number of 1m long cars on a stripe of length $n$. To apply that to your question, one has to use that the expected number $N$ of  3m long cars on a 300m long stripe is the same as the expected number of 1m long cars on a 100m long stripe, which yields $$
  N \approx M(100) \approx 74.51 \text{.}
$$

Comment: Yes this i understand, Is there a different, simpler way to getting to this answer (or close to it) without the complicated math?

Comment: @user75013 Honestly? I dunno! Judging from the fact that, as the link *clearly* explains, these things are the subject of academic publications, probably not. Maybe one could find upper and lower bounds in some easy fashion, but how that would work exactly seems far from obvious. So, you'll either have to play with this yourself, or use these results. Or, of course, simply do a computer simulation!

Comment: I need to show creative thought and somehow reach an answer to solve this problem, it probably should be close to this answer i assume.Since i'm a law student i have no idea on how to do a simulation :(

Comment: @user75013 To be honest, asking for others to solve it for you while at the same time stating that you "need to show creative thought" is, to put it mildly, somewhat weird... Weird enough that, despite the fact that I find this problem interesting, I don't particularly feel like putting any more effort into this. Good luck!

Comment: Well, never thought that at my age people will still try to educate me :) but thank you anyway. BTW - I did try handling this for the past 2 weeks and even before I posed this question, only with a limited knowledge in math it is quite hard. Also, you didn't ask what attempts I made or what results I got, instead you chose the "teacher"'s side. so, I guess you can also learn something about yourself from this riddle and also how you can behave better for the future. Best of luck and thank you for what you did contribute.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(r)$ be the expected number of cars that will park in an interval of length $r$.
By considering what happens when the first car comes along, we should have
$$ f(r) = \cases{ 0 & if $r < 1$\cr
                 1 + \frac{1}{r-1} \int_0^{r-1} ds\; (f(s) + f(r-1-s))\cr
                 \ = 1 + \frac{2}{r-1} \int_0^{r-1} ds \; f(s) & otherwise}$$
So:

If $1 \le r < 2$, $f(r) = 1$.

If $2 \le r < 3$, $f(r) = 1 + \frac{2 (r-2)}{r-1} = 3 - \frac{2}{r-1} $.

etc.

Unfortunately, by the time we get to $6 < r < 7$, the integrals can't be done in closed form.